# Handle assertion dialog box with python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, assert

I am using python to create a sub process to check and see that no assertions occur.

I want to catch the error output along with the return code. That works fine, but the problem I run into is that when it runs into the assertion it gives me a dialog box that just hangs there. I have to then click the assertion box before I retrieve any information. Is there a way to make it not pop up and continue with the program or to send a message to close the window?

This is a problem since this is an automation service.

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen('test2.exe', shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in pipe.stderr:
    print line
```

The executable is compiled from c++ code and has an assertion that will fail for testing purposes.

Comment: What Python environment are your running your code in? I've never had a pop-up associated with an assertion.

Comment: sorry I should have clarified. I am calling an executable with Popen

Answer (score 1):

There's not really an easy solution in general, since a program could in theory create any number of windows waiting for user input.  If you have the source code for the inferior process, the easiest thing to do would be to modify it to call [`_set_abort_behavior(0, _CALL_REPORTFAULT)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e631wekh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to disable the message box.

If you don't have the source code, it's going to be much, much tougher.  You could probably write a big hack that did something like attaching a debugger to the inferior process and setting a breakpoint on the call to `abort()`.  If that breakpoint gets hit, kill the process and return an appropriate error status.  But that's an extreme non-trivial kludge.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, pop-ups for assertions isn't a normal thing in Python. If you can modify the code running in a subprocess, you might be able to capture the assertion and handle it yourself, rather than letting the environment handle it with a popup.

```
import sys

try:
    code that raises the assertion
catch AssertionError, e:
    sys.stderr.write("Assertion failed: " + str(e))
    sys.exit(1)
```

If it's looking for assertions in particular, this should work, because it will capture the assertion, print an error message and then raise a simple `SystemExit` exception instead.